# Is there any default nameserver for HaProxy resolvers?

Tags: haproxy

I use HaProxy to forward traffic to a backend server which has a dns name instead of network address:

```
backend default-backend
    server external somedomain.com:80
```

The problem is that there is a situation when it can become not resolvable.
In this case HaProxy says:

> Server default-backend/external is going DOWN for maintenance (DNS NX status). 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
>   backend default-backend has no server available!

I would like HaProxy to check for DNS resolution again and start forwarding traffic whenever target DNS name is resolvable again.
The problem is that I have to declare `resolvers` section and at least one `nameserver` which can resolve such address like this:

```
resolvers rslvr
    nameserver dns0 8.8.8.8:53
```

What if I do not like to declare any resolvers? I just want HaProxy checked DNS resolution the same way it does on startup. Is it possible?

If I do not use a resolver, backend just stops working and does not check if this domain is available again. Same thing happens when I do not have any `nameserver` in `resolvers` section.

Is there any way to omit explicit `nameserver` declaration or maybe use some default resolver used by HaProxy on startup?

Comment: What version of HAProxy? (`haproxy -v`)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot 1.8.8, not that old :)

Comment: I'm not sure you're fixing the right problem.  Without `resolvers foo` on the `server` line, HAProxy should not try to resolve the host after startup unless that is relatively new behavior.  Are you sure it us a resolution problem, or is it that the server address changes, but HAProxy doesn't *try* to look it up again?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Ok, without *resolvers* I can't achieve what I want, as I understand it was never possible and there is no such new feature. Anyway I do not like the idea of specifying `nameserver`s explicitly. So I ask if there is a kind of an alias on default nameserver which would resolve the same way HAProxy does on startup?

Comment: Your question was very unclear.  I see now, what you want -- use the system resolver settings so that runtime resolution is the same as startup, without explicit configuration.  I've seen discussion about this on the mailing list, but I don't think that feature will be included until 1.9.  If you are running this in AWS, then `nameserver vpc 169.254.169.253:53` is a magic value that works, regardless of your VPC's IP address range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

haproxy version 1.9 introduced a new parameter for the resolvers section which removes the need to manually list the nameservers.

```
parse-resolv-conf
```

See [their docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#5.3.2-parse-resolv-conf) for more info but essentially this allows you to replace

```
resolvers mydns
  nameserver dns1 10.0.0.1:53
  nameserver dns2 10.0.0.2:53
  hold valid           10s
```

with

```
resolvers mydns
  parse-resolv-conf
  hold valid           10s
```

assuming your resolv.conf (which is read by haproxy when you don't have a resolvers section) has 10.0.0.1:53 and 10.0.0.2:53 configured.